# Xampp could not open log file sslkey.log

Tags: apache, xampp

I have rune XAMPP in adminstrator mode, when I click "start" apache server. It returns this:

```
20:41:51  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
20:41:51  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
20:41:51  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:41:51  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:41:51  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:41:51  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:41:51  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
20:41:51  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I checked the error logs and it states this:

```
[Tue Feb 15 20:41:51.126535 2022] [ssl:notice] [pid 6152:tid 576] (OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : AH10226: Could not open log file 'C:\\Users\\Zen\\Desktop\\SSLKEY\\sslkey.log' configured via SSLKEYLOGFILE
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

I have looked all over the internet and found nobody with the same issue. I have reinstalled XAMPP three times now, and restarted my PC each time.

I apologize if this is easy to solve, I am new to XAMPP and web development.

Thank you,
Zen

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I have no idea why XAMPP, despite numerous reinstallations, was presuming that "C:\Users\Zen\Desktop\SSLKEY\sslkey.log" path existed.
But I simply created a folder on my desktop, and then created a file called  sslkey.log (with nothing in it), and Apache now works.

Sorry it is a simple fix, I am brand new to web development.